# Who wants a FizzBuzz?

Tags: beginner, fizzbuzz, io-lang

I have been playing around with the Io language, and this is my second toy, after the `yes` program that is just `loop ("yes" printl)` and on which not much review is possible, I wrote a FizzBuzz program. I like the shortness of it, but any improvement is welcome as I am very beginner in this programming language.

```
toBuzzWord := method(n,
   if (n % 15 == 0, "FizzBuzz",
   if (n % 5 == 0, "Fizz",
   if (n % 3 == 0, "Buzz", n))))

for (i, 1, 100, toBuzzWord(i) println)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From discussion elsewhere I know you don't want to change the basic implementation, so I'll confine my comments to idiom, style and tweaks.

I would replace the `for` loop with a `foreach`

```
Range // addon reference required in newer versions
1 to(100) foreach(i, toBuzzWord(i) println)
```

The Range protocol used to be in the core library but is now an add-on, hence the reference needed before you can use it.  That said, it's a more idiomatic, expressive and robust way to deal with simple ranges.  `for` loops are even more fragile in Io than in C-like languages, given the optional parameter and Io's blithe tolerance of extra parameters.

I don't like chained if-then-elsif in any language, even when it's a function and not a keyword.  One alternative would be to use `return`

```
method(n,
   if (n % 15 == 0, return "FizzBuzz")
   if (n % 5 == 0, return "Fizz")
   if (n % 3 == 0, return "Buzz")
   return n
)
```

Multiple exit points from a function are much debated and criticised, but

1. Io has no switch or case function and the community doesn't want one.
2. lists (using a numeric index lookup) or maps (using a string key) are sometimes used for very simple switch-style control flows but that doesn't work here.

In purist OO style, Io developers prefer to use (no surprise here) polymorphism.  Send a message and let the inheritance chain pick the appropriate action.

Polymorphism is really overkill for the simple fizzBuzz implementation you have chosen.  It *might* be useful for a more efficient solution.